# NPE while filter list with io.reactivex.Observable

Tags: android, iterator, rx-java2, rx-android

I facing with problem while try to filter `ArrayList` of `String` as `Observable`.

All works fine if:

```
MatrixCursor suggestionsCursor =
        new MatrixCursor(new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, COLUMN_FIELD_NO});

for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    if (data.get(i) != null)
        if (data.get(i).toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase()))
            filtered.add(data.get(i));
}

int key = 0;
for (String suggestion : filtered) {
    suggestionsCursor.addRow(new Object[]{key++, suggestion});
}
```

But not if

```
MatrixCursor suggestionsCursor =
        new MatrixCursor(new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, COLUMN_FIELD_NO});

Observable.fromIterable(data)
        .filter(it->it!=null && it.toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase()))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .toList()
        .subscribe(strings -> {
            int key = 0;
            for (String suggestion : strings) {
                suggestionsCursor.addRow(new Object[]{key++, suggestion});
            }          
        });
```

Because I get an error

> io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The iterator
>   returned a null value

Where am I wrong here?

Comment: Trying to work with a sequence containing nulls. Nulls are not allowed and not accepted in a flow and filter would never receive a null item. You have to pre-filter the iterable and remove nulls before it is handed to RxJava.

Comment: @Anton feel free to accept one of the answers below if you think it is appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answears are good, but I found easier solution.

```
data.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

After populate data with `Strings`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, `null` values in the iterable sequence are not supported. This check is enforced in the `ObservableFromIterable.java` class:

```
v = ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(it.next(), "The iterator returned a null value");
```

This also means that a filter like this does not help

```
.filter(it -> it != null)
```

In any case, a good rule of thumb will be to handle error exceptions

```
Observable.fromIterable(data)
        .filter(it->it!=null && it.toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase()))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .toList()
        .subscribe(strings -> {
            int key = 0;
            for (String suggestion : strings) {
                suggestionsCursor.addRow(new Object[]{key++, suggestion});
            }          
        }, error -> {
           /* handle exceptions here */
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Iterable Extensions library ([IxJava](https://github.com/akarnokd/ixjava#examples)) for preprocessing, which let's you work with `null`s:

```java
Observable.fromIterable(
        Ix.from(data)
        .filter(it -> it != null 
             && it.toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())
        )
    )
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .toList()
    .subscribe(strings -> {
        int key = 0;
        for (String suggestion : strings) {
            suggestionsCursor.addRow(new Object[]{key++, suggestion});
        }          
    }, 
    Throwable::printStackTrace);
```